# Imagetool Grid to PNG silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a project using Imagetools library transfer grid to PNG image, this is

part of the picture :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXVYN.png) (bad one)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoqzy.png) (good one)

it's textblock inside grid, and set color

looks normal when show on the screen, but when output to PNG image

it will looks like this, with black line under

here is my code

```
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)tempGrid.Width, (int)tempGrid.Height);

        bitmap.Render(tempGrid, new TranslateTransform());
        bitmap.Invalidate();

        ExtendedImage img = bitmap.ToImage() ;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream() ;
        PngEncoder encoder = new PngEncoder() ;
        encoder.Encode(img, ms);
        ms.Position = 0;

        long bytesRead = stream.Read(binaryData, 0, (int)stream.Length);

        string base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(binaryData, 0, 
         binaryData.Length);
```

then I write the bas64 string to png image

did I miss any setting ?

is it possible to get rid of the black line ?

thanks

Comment: can you please post both the images you see (the good one) and the one you wrote (the bad one with black lines) ?

Comment: Ok ! I post the good one